# how to start progress-bar after sometime of interval

Tags: wpf

I have wpf application with  progressbar. I want to start it after 1 minute. my progress bar working properly just want to start after specific time period.

code for progressbar

```
public login()
{
  InitilizeComponent()
  DispatcherTimer timer= new Timer(1000);
  timer.Elapsed+= timer_Elapsed;
  timer.start();
}
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
thsi.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherProperty.Normal,(Action)() =>
{
    if (progressBar<20)
     {
        progressBar.value+=1;
     }
      else
      {
             timer.stop();
      }
} 
)
}
```

Comment: Use a second timer, that will start the first timer after a minute instead of directly in the constructor?

Comment: will u please elaborate...I did not get that second timer. What is it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of async/await methods and a timer to achieve this:

DispatcherTimer timerProgressBar;

```
    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Create the timer
        timerProgressBar = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerProgressBar.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
        timerProgressBar.Tick += timerProgressBar_Tick;

        //Start waiting
        WaitForProgressBar();
    }

    void timerProgressBar_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (progressBar.Value < 20)
                    progressBar.Value++;
                else
                    timerProgressBar.Stop();
            });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Begins waiting for 1 minute before starting the timer.
    /// </summary>
    public async void WaitForProgressBar()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)));

        timerProgressBar.Start();
    }
```

Using the async method, this will keep your UI responsive during the wait period. If this isn't what was intended then simply change the async methods to synchronous.

Comment: OP, have you given this a try? Are you still having problems?